# Theoretical basis of a technique for proving a limit by definition (basic first calculus course question)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

IMPORTANT QUESTION (first post)

Given an example of a proof of the limit of $a(n): n/((n^2) + 1)$ is 0.

Proof by definition:
$|n/((n^2) + 1)-0| < \varepsilon \Longleftrightarrow |n/((n^2) + 1) |< \varepsilon$
this is the step where my question comes: as far as I know, I can increase the left expression: $n/((n^2) + 1)$ and the proof will still work.

Can you please explain why does that work and if I can also increase the expression by adding the variable $n$ in the numerator/subtracting it from the denominator or it's only valid for constants? can someone please give me a full theoretical explanation of this technique for proving limits?

At first I thought it should be the complete opposite, which means that I can decrease the left expression so that if its value was 5, $5<\varepsilon$ and then became 3, then $3<5<\varepsilon$ which is really still valid algebraically. (if $\varepsilon$ is greater than 5 and 5 is greater than 3 then $\varepsilon$ is greater than 3 for sure).

But the opposite is not necessarily true (if I increase the expression). So why does it still work ?! does the explanation have an algebraic basis or is it related to the definition of the limit?

Comment: $0<\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\frac{n}{n^2}$ so the inner sequence is "sandwiched" between the two outer sequences.  Both of the two outer sequences tend towards zero so the middle one must as well.  See [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry but that was not my question, it's much more basic than squeeze theorem. I couldn't explain myself mathematically more clearly.

Comment: You can't change the expression $n/(n^2+1)$ by adding something in numerator or subtracting something in denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a valid question, and what's important here is to notice the direction of implication:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, the goal is to find a $C$ such that $n > C \implies |a(n)-0| < \epsilon$.

So here $\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\epsilon$ is the conclusion you wish to prove. By increasing the left hand side, for example to $\frac{n}{n^2}$, you obtain a stronger statement:

$$\frac{n}{n^2}< \epsilon \implies \frac{n}{n^2+1}< \epsilon$$

And if you can prove that the first statement is true for all $n>C$, you also proved that the second statement is true for all $n>C$.

---

Using your simplified example, you are right that $5<\epsilon \implies 3<\epsilon$. But in other words, that means knowing $3<\epsilon$ does not always help to prove that $5<\epsilon$; there are counter examples of $\epsilon$ between $3$ and $5$.

On the other hand, by increasing the left hand side from $5$ to $7$, knowing $7<\epsilon$ means also knowing that $5<\epsilon$.